# Checking if -touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event is inside a certain rect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to trigger a segue if the finger is lifted when you are inside the rectangle area (touchUpInside). No idea how to do this. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: do you have any code to show or something?

Comment: `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNowPlaying" sender:self];
}`

Comment: @MarkBourke Get one touches from the touches set, and perform function `CGRectContainsPoint(rect, aPoint)` to see if the touch was lifted inside the rect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  CGRect targetRect = CGRectZero; // replace this with the rect the user has to touch to trigger the segue

  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  if (CGRectContainsPoint(targetRect, touchLocation)) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
  }
}
```